# Running monit on Suse SLED 10

Tags: monit, sles10

Can anyone tell me how to get [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to start at boot on Suse SLED 10 ?

Suse seems to do services different than everyone else. 
I found a link to a monit init file, but I don't think it will work out of the box.

http://code.google.com/p/monit/source/browse/trunk/contrib/packages/suse/7.3/monit.init?r=2#

Answer (score 0):

Have you used 'yast' to adjust your startup configuration?  Does it appear in that list?

Comment: Monit is not in any repos I can use. I have installed monit from source.

Comment: Have you moved the startup configuration file which should come with the source distribution into the /etc/init.d directory? –

Comment: I have a config file in there, that I pulled from OpenSuse, I'm going to try to modify it and getting up and working